Java project, parsing/processing live train data
I am absolutely stuck and stumped on this, I've tried everything to parse/process the live output. This is the output I receive from a .jar application simulating live train data:
Simulator output:
R: T1(R02, F), T2(R07, F), T3(R38, B), T4(R42, B)
Processing train data: R: T1(R02, F), T2(R07, F), T3(R38, B), T4(R42, B)

but then I keep getting this when I process it:
Processing train entry: T1(R02
Unrecognized train data format: T1(R02
Processing train entry: F)
Unrecognized train data format: F)

private void processTrainData(String line) {
    System.out.println("Processing train data: " + line);

    if (line.equals("Train positions:")) {
        return;
    }

    String[] sections = line.split(": ");
    if (sections.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Unrecognized train data format: " + line);
        return;
    }

    String[] trainData = sections[1].split(", ");
    for (String train : trainData) {
        System.out.println("Processing train entry: " + train);

        // Regular expression to match train number, station code, and direction
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("T(\\d+)\\((\\w{3}), ([FB])\\)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(train);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            int trainNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
            String stationCode = matcher.group(2);
            String direction = matcher.group(3).equals("F") ? "forward" : "backward";

            System.out.println("Train number: " + trainNumber);
            System.out.println("Station code: " + stationCode);
            System.out.println("Direction: " + direction);

            Point coordinates = trainMap.getStationCoordinates(stationCode);
            if (coordinates != null) {
                System.out.println("Parsed train data - Train number: " + trainNumber + ", coordinates: ("
                        + coordinates.x + ", " + coordinates.y + ")");
                trainPositions.put(trainNumber, coordinates);

                // Update the next train panel for the tracked train
                if (trainNumber == trackedTrainNumber) {
                    Station currentStation = trainTracker.getStation(stationCode);
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> updateNextTrainStations(currentStation));
                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("No coordinates found for station: " + stationCode);
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("Unrecognized train data format: " + train);
        }
    }
}

and this is my code, why does it keep triggering the unrecognized train data format?

Have you tried stepping through with a debugger? Its a good time to learn how, or at the very least how to interpret your own error statements, since you do actually print out the state of the string that has an error. I can definitely tell you that your split() is splitting it in a way you do not expect though.

Try to check your regex if it matches the input you are providing and the data chunks which your split method is providing, that seems to be the initial point of your error train. You can use any online regex checker like regex101 to put in regex and data to check if they match up!

I believe you should improve the formatting of this post (code, input and output) || the problem: think about what split(", ") is doing? For example for this part (R02, F) (as suggested above, use a debugger to confirm the result of it, content of trainData) - that split is not needed at all, just loop calling find() until it returns false

As someone said in a comment: you split too much.
Try something like this:
        String line = "R: T1(R02, F), T2(R07, F), T3(R38, B), T4(R42, B)";
        if (line.equals("Train positions:")) {
            return;
        }

        String[] sections = line.split(": ");
        if (sections.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Unrecognized train data format: " + line);
            return;
        }

        // Regular expression to match train number, station code, and direction
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("T(\\d+)\\((\\w{3}), ([FB])\\)(?:, (.*))?");
        String section = sections[1];
        do {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(section);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                int trainNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                String stationCode = matcher.group(2);
                String direction = matcher.group(3).equals("F") ? "forward" : "backward";
                section = matcher.group(4);

                System.out.println("Train number: " + trainNumber);
                System.out.println("Station code: " + stationCode);
                System.out.println("Direction: " + direction);

//                Point coordinates = trainMap.getStationCoordinates(stationCode);
//                if (coordinates != null) {
//                    System.out.println("Parsed train data - Train number: " + trainNumber + ", coordinates: ("
//                            + coordinates.x + ", " + coordinates.y + ")");
//                    trainPositions.put(trainNumber, coordinates);
//
//                    // Update the next train panel for the tracked train
//                    if (trainNumber == trackedTrainNumber) {
//                        Station currentStation = trainTracker.getStation(stationCode);
//                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> updateNextTrainStations(currentStation));
//                    }
//                } else {
//                    System.err.println("No coordinates found for station: " + stationCode);
//                }
            } else {
                System.err.println("Unrecognized train data format: " + section);
                break;
            }
        } while (section != null);
    }


You are having a problem becuae of the comma (,) delimiter also located within the bracketed content of the train data being split. You need to ignore those specific commas when splitting the data since Pattern/Matcher needs it. It could possibly be something similar to this:
String liveTrainData = "R: T1(R02, F), T2(R07, F), T3(R38, B), T4(R42, B)";
String rawTrainData = liveTrainData.split(":")[1].trim();
String regex = ",\\s+(?![^\\(\\)]*\\))";
String[] trainData = rawTrainData.split(regex);

for (String train : trainData) {
    System.out.println("Processing train entry: -> " + train);

    // Regular expression to match train number, station code, and direction
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)T(\\d+)\\((\\w{3}),\\s*([FB])\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(train);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int trainNumber = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        String stationCode = matcher.group(2);
        String direction = matcher.group(3).equalsIgnoreCase("F") ? "Forward" : "Backward";

        System.out.println("Train number: " + trainNumber);
        System.out.println("Station code: " + stationCode);
        System.out.println("Direction: " + direction);
        System.out.println();

        // .... Removed this code since we don't have privy to that ...
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Unrecognized train data format: " + train);
    }
}

When the above code is run, the following is displayed within the Console Window:
Processing train entry: -> T1(R02, F)
Train number: 1
Station code: R02
Direction: Forward

Processing train entry: -> T2(R07, F)
Train number: 2
Station code: R07
Direction: Forward

Processing train entry: -> T3(R38, B)
Train number: 3
Station code: R38
Direction: Backward

Processing train entry: -> T4(R42, B)
Train number: 4
Station code: R42
Direction: Backward

